# Will have written or have written

Tags: word-choice, difference

There is a text: "Will you give me the article after you (write) you homework." I would like to know, what is better to put: will have written or have written?

Comment: When you say "There is a text", do you mean that you wrote this sentence or that you found it somewhere? A native speaker would say _...when you have done your homework_.

Answer (score 1):

To answer what I think is your main question: native English speakers hardly ever use the modal "will" (often misleadingly referred to as "the future tense") in temporal clauses (introduced by expressions such as "when", "after", "before").

So *after you will have written* is not idiomatic - in any context as far as I can think. *After you have written* is OK, but as another reply says *After you finish* is even more normal.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your sentence. What do you want to say? If it is a question it needs a question mark at the end. If it is an instruction you don't need "will you."

[In the UK:] As Kate Bunting said, children **do** their homework: they don't write it. We say, "...after you've done your homework" or, more commonly, "...when you've done your homework."

If the child has already started doing his/her homework we might say, "...when you've *finished* your homework."

If the 'article' refers to the homework, we might ask, "Will you give me your homework when you've done/finished it?"

If the homework is to *write an article* (for the school magazine, perhaps) then we might ask, "Will you give me the article when you've written it?"